# Cucumber html report causes test failure

Tags: ruby, cucumber, reporting

I'm running tests in parallel on Cucumber using parallel_cucumber.

I'm finding that when I choose to have the reports in junit, everything runs smoothly.  If I change the format of the test to html, some tests keep failing.  Yet running them in isolation, no parallel_cucumber and it works fine.  I switch it back to junit and the tests all pass again.

The errors I'm getting are unable to find fields on screen.  Could the html be messing with the step definitions?  I've searched and searched and can't figure out why it's failing.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue?

My cucumber.yml file contains:

```
html: --format pretty --format html --out Reports/report<%= ENV['TEST_ENV_NUMBER']%>.html --format ParallelTests::Cucumber::FailuresLogger --out Reports/cucumber_failures.log
```

my junit profile is:

```
junit: --format pretty --format junit --out Reports/ --format ParallelTests::Cucumber::FailuresLogger --out Reports/cucumber_failures.log
```

Answer (score 0):

On trial and error, I found that it was the background steps causing the failure.  I moved these to the scenarios and lo and behold, the tests stopped failing